# Avoid 'downpassing' of dependencies to Entity subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, dependency-injection, singleton, composite

I have the following problem:

I have a superclass called `Entity`, which provides some basic methods every entity has. For this, it needs some services to run such as `AbstractPotionService`. This dependency is needed by none of its subclasses directly, but I would have to pass it every time I instantiate a sub-type of an Entity such as `MobileEntity`

```java
public class Entity {
  
  private AbstractPotionService potionService;
  protected EntityTypeConverter converter;

  public Entity(EntityTypeConverter converter, AbstractPotionService potionService) {
    this.converter = converter;
    this.potionService = potionService;
  }

  public void addEffect(EffectType effectType, int durationInSeconds) {
    potionservice.applyEffectTo(this, effectType, durationInSeconds);
  }

  ...

}
```

```java
public class MobileEntity extends Entity {

  public MobileEntity(EntityTypeConverter converter, AbstractPotionService potionService){
    super(converter, potionService);
  }

  public attack(MobileEntity victim) {
   ...
  }

  ...

}
```

This feels kind of wrong as it is a lot of tedious work and makes the project less maintainable when I want to extend the `Entity` class. My first thought was to use a Singleton here and get an instance of the services in the constructor of `Entity` directly (via static methods), but wouldn't that create a God dependency?

I also read about composition but I couldn't find an appropriate example on how to apply it in my case. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe a factory pattern would help: a client would use a factory to create instances of Entitys or subclasses by method; the factory would be initialized with the desired converter or portion service.  Different factories could exist with different configurations.  All this would do is move the responsiblity from the client to the factory.  https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: It smells like you're mixing responsibilities here; why is the `Entity` (which is normally just a data object) responsible for all these side operations?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: Having domain methods as part of your entities is a very common pattern in Domain-Driven Design. Having these methods inside your entities does, however, easily cause entities to become ever growing classes, which can be seen as a SRP violation.

Comment: @Andy: I would be careful in advising factories. In DIPP&P, Mark and I warn about abuse of abuse of factories in [chapter 6](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6). Also see [Abstract Factories are a Code Smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/).

Answer (score 4):

Chapter 4 (page 106) of [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (DIPP&P) (that I coauthored) states:

> Entities that contain behavior besides their usual set of data members would easily get a wide range of methods, each requiring their own dependencies. Although you might be tempted to use Constructor Injection to inject such dependencies, that leads to a situation where each such entity needs to be created with all of its dependencies, even though only a few may be necessary for a given use case. This complicates testing the logic of an entity, because all dependencies need to be supplied to the constructor, even though a test might only be interested in a few dependencies. **Method Injection [...] offers a better alternative.**

The case of the required constructor dependencies is even exaggerated in your case, because every sub type needs to have those dependencies in their own constructor and need to pass them through to the `Entity` base type. If you add a new dependency to `Entity` it will cause *all* derived entities to change (and with them, all their tests), which can cause maintainability issues.

So instead, DIPP&P advises the use of [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) instead which, in your case, would look like this:

```cs
public class Entity {
  
  public Entity() { } // <-- No more Constructor Injection

  public void addEffect(
    EffectType effectType,
    int durationInSeconds,
    AbstractPotionService potionService) // <-- Method Injection
  {
    potionservice.applyEffectTo(this, effectType, durationInSeconds);
  }

  ...
}
```

With Method Injection, the method requiring the dependency is supplied with that dependency. And while the method uses the dependency, unlike Constructor Injection, it *doesn't store* the dependency.

This has the effect that its now the consumer's responsibility to supply the correct dependency. In most cases it would mean that the dependency is injected into the consumer using [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/).

Comment: Hello @Steven , it is true that it complicates testing, but on the other hand it furnish a better API, the class can be used "as is" instead of providing a bunch of method dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers/comments. With [@Steven's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) answer and [@Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711811/andy) comment, I was able to build a solution. As already pointed out in Steven's answer, using pure method injection every time an effect is added might not be the cleanest solution as you would have to request the dependency in any class using this method.

So I took the idea of using a factory class to create my entities. After it has checked the entity type and injected the specific data, some method injections are done at the end:

```java
public Entity createEntity(EntityType type) {
  Entity output = new Entity();

  if (type == EntityType.MONSTER) {
   output = new MonsterEntity(someMonsterDependency);
  } else if (type == EntityType.PLAYER) {
   output = new PlayerEntity(somePlayerDependencies);
  } if (type == EntityType.FRIENDLY_NPC) {
   ...
  }

  output.setPotionService(potionService);
  output.injectOtherDependencies...

  return output;

}
```

So now, I only have to load the service implementations on startup, inject them into my `EntityFactory`, and can then create entities. If someone still has a better solution, feel free to post it.

Comment: You should also examine the _Replace Conditional With Polymorphism_ refactoring; chains of `else if` or `switch`, _especially_ with Java enums, are a code smell.